# bcrypt compare method is returning false even if I used the same string when I hashed it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, bcrypt

When I use the same password I hashed and stored in database as a parameter in compare method I get false. Really don't know whats the problem here:

router:

```
router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(
            req.body.email,
            req.body.password
        );
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
        console.log("Route token -->", token);
        res.send({ user, token });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(errors.e400);
    }
});
```

Method for email and password validation ( calling compare method here):

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) throw new Error("User does not exist.");

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) throw new Error("Invalid password.");

    return user;
};
```

password hashing:

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function () {
    try {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 8);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value))
                throw new Error("Email address is not valid.");
        },
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        minLength: 7,
    },
    tokens: [
        {
            token: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

Comment: I remember bcrypt using a callback function and not working with await. Have tried seeing what the error is? It might not even be related to your password. EDIT: Just checked the docs and it seems like it is now compatible with async/wait.

Comment: @justanotherguy No, bcrypt functions return promises, so you can await. You have examples in the docs: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js

Comment: When using the `bcrypt.compare()` function, for the first parameter, are you passing the plain password or did you hash it? The first param must be a plain text password, while the second one must be the password hash.

Comment: I figured out...my pre method was total mess.